# Error with bulk loading into hbase

Tags: hbase, bulk

When I performed bulk loading data into hbase with shell command like below.

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf1:val1,cf1:val2,cf1:val3 so_table /tmp/example/
```

I made a file and load into hdfs like `/tmp/example/`.
Each ingredient of each line is separated by space.
I think this separator-space- result in all lines look like bad line.
Is there a way to use a separator with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Use `'-Dimporttsv.separator=" "'`.

Answer (score 0):

ImportTsv has two usages. One is just a normal put, and other is bulk load. The command you gave above is for regular Put. But in the question, you specify it as bulk load. Please choose the correct option.

So once, the usage is decided, then comes the separator part. `'-Dimporttsv.separator=" "'` is how you use separator. Default is tab separated. Look [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_importtsv) for proper usage of ImportTsv